# URL style LaTeX change?

Tags: hyperref

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{libertine}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-2]
\url{http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/ask}
\lipsum[1-2]
\end{document}
```

As you can see here, the URL style is different to the normal fontlayout and sting one directly in the eye. How to change that? I would like to have a style which looks like the text (just with the difference that you could click on it).

Kind regards!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add

```
\urlstyle{rm}
```

to your preamble.